# How to import PHPMailer into a class which uses namespace?

Tags: php, namespaces, phpmailer

I'm having the following project folders and files: (note that I want to separate my classes from the libraries (such as PHPMailer, HTMLPurifier, etc))

[image]

In my Register.php file I'm having the Register class:

```
namespace Classes\Register;

class Register
{
    public function register()
    {
        // ...
        $m = new PHPMailer;
        // send email
    }
}
```

So, in my Register class (located into the classes/ directory), I want to use PHPMailer class (located one directory above, relative to Register.php file, into libs/PHPMailer). How can I include the PHPMailer class into the Register.php file?

I've tried:

```
 $m = new \PHPMailer; // to use the class from the global scope, but it doesn't work.
```

or, if I include the PHPMailerAutoload.php, like so:

```
namespace Classes\Register;

require '../libs/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

// and then into register() method:
$m = new PHPMailer;
```

I'm getting an error stating: `Fatal error: Class 'Classes\Register\PHPMailer' not found`

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have given no reason why this doesn't work, because it is correct:

```
 $m = new \PHPMailer;
```

Alternatively you can import the class into your own namespace:

```
use PHPMailer;

$m = new PHPMailer;
```

It's basically the same regarding the class name.

If both versions don't work, you have a different problem.

Comment: If I do it like `$m = new \PHPMailer;` , and without using any other `use` or `require`, then I'm getting this error: `Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found` in the line where I instantiate the PHPMailer class. Could the problem be because I'm using Win7 and I'm working on `localhost`?

Comment: "Without using any `require`" sounds wrong, you have to have the autoloader executed before you use any classes.

Comment: Ok! I will try to use your way. For now I will accept your answer as the solution. Thank. I'll be back with a response if it's working or not...