Sending mail with phpmailer and mollie not working
I am using the payment provider Mollie and try to send mail after a succesfull payment.
On top of the webhook php I have "namespace _PhpScoper08ed470ac589;" for the Mollie API.
A little bit further on the webhook.php:
if ($payment -> isPaid() && !$payment -> hasRefunds() && !$payment -> hasChargebacks()) { // payment is succesfull so send a mail to the client

    include_once('/home/xxx/domains/xxx.nl/public_html/classes/phpmailer/mail.php');

    $mail = new Mail();
    ...
    $mail->send();
}

No mail is sending right now.
In the error log I see "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class '_PhpScoper08ed470ac589\classes' not found" on the line with "$mail = new Mail();"
It looks like the class new Mail() is getting from _PhpScoper08ed470ac589 in stead of the PHPMailer class.
I have tried to change the line to $mail = new classes/phpmailer/Mail(); but that doesn't did the trick.
Any idea how to get the PHPMailer to work so I can send a confirmation mail with an invoice?

Add a use statement for the PHPMailer namespace, or prefix the class name with \ - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31061819/1427878

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer?tab=readme-ov-file#installation--loading

Is there any good reason to include a class directly, instead of using Composer to install the whole package?

We can't tell what's going on here. Mail.php is not part of PHPMailer, so it looks like you're using some wrapper. As Nico said, you should be using composer.

the prefixing of the class Mail did the trick for me
